# RTSP stream resolution

Tags: nest-device-access

According to the [documentation for CameraLiveStream](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream), it should be possible to select the resolution of the RTSP stream coming from cameras:

Quoting from the link above:

> **width**: Maximum image resolution width. May also be used as a query parameter in the download URL.
> **height**: Maximum image resolution height. May also be used as a query parameter in the download URL.

It's unclear where those parameters are to be put.

1. I tried putting them as query string parameters in the request to the RTSP feed, for example `rtsps://someurl.com/CjY5Y3VKaTZwR3o4Y19YbTVfMF...?auth=g.0.streamingToken&width=800` - in this case, nothing seems to happen: the video feed continues to be 1920x1080 (depending on the combination of width/height I set, sometimes I get a 404 error)
2. I tried putting it in the `params` dictionary in the request body to the `executeCommand` request. This gives me a bad request error.
3. Likewise, putting it as query string in the request to `executeCommand` gives me another API error like bad request.

How does the API work? The documentation doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "download URL" mentioned is when requesting an event image, not the stream itself.  As far as I know the only way to change the stream is to change the settings on the camera itself.

https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9218596?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation